Fixing a split door frame on the hinge side
I know similar questions get asked a lot, but every instance I could find here was either a far more general question than I have, or is asking about fixing a split frame on the latch side (usually due to someone kicking the door in).
I have a nearly 40 year old house, and I think the front door may be original equipment. Its solid wood, and hugely heavy.
In the last couple of weeks the door has not been wanting to swing properly. Now it flat out doesn't want to shut. My harried handyman suggested I just go buy a new pre-framed door and replace the whole shebang myself (he's too busy to do it right now).
I finally got a chance to take a good hard look at it, and it looks to me like what has happened is the extreme weight of the door has caused the wood on the frame to split away from itself over time. There's a linear crack clean up the hinge side of the frame that gets wider as you go up. Pretty sure this is the sole culprit for the door hanging issues.
Here's a photo of the door (almost) closed. You can see that crack in the wood to the right of the top hinge, and that it continues down past the second hinge.

Below are some pictures of the frame with the door open (and old-timey metal flashing) showing the split in the wood of the frame. Pictures are in order the top hinge, in between the hinges, and the mid hinge.



What I'm wondering is what all I need to do to fix this? Perhaps I can just unhinge the door, glue and clamp the frame back together, then perhaps replace the hinge screws with longer ones?

This is a 2 part issue.
The door frame is apparently coming away from the house framing. This is something your handyman should be able to repair.
What you are seeing is not a split in the frame it is a split in the caulking between the trim and the door frame. (Because the door frame is moving.)
The cure is to caulk the split with acrylic caulk. When dry paint.
As far as the door sagging so it won't close, that can be cured by tightening the screws in the top and middle hinge.  You may need to replace them with longer screws to better grip the structural framing.

I think you may be right, which sadly means that probably has nothing to do with the door hanging problem.

As for the tightening, I'll have to remove that old flashing/weather stripping to check. The wife wants that stuff gone anyway though, so small loss.

@T.E.D.  Longer screws might help with the door hanging, if the hinge screws are loose.

@crip659 - None of them were loose. Still replaced one in the top hinge with a 3" deck screw, because my wife thought the same thing, so doing it made her happier.

@T.E.D.  Hinge screws are the easiest to fix and happy wife is good, but if they do not fix the problem, life gets more interesting.  If screws do not fix the problem, then it moves to door frame moving/house moving.  Check if the door frame is plumb and square and level.

Check the screws that hold the hinges on to the door too. The weight of the door could have worked on them as well as the ones in the door frame. You may need to install longer screws there too.
